# How to grab params from URL in react-router v 2.+

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to grab the value of a key form URL. Let's say the URL is http://localhost:8080/foo=bar. How do I grab the value 'bar' onEnter function with in react-router so that it can be used to trigger other functions.

Thank you in advance.

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/foo=bar

// routes.js

var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Main = require('./templates/main.jsx');
var Sub = require('./templates/sub.jsx');

module.exports = {
        path: '/',
        component: Main,
        indexRoute: { component: Main },
        childRoutes: [
            {
                path: '/foo=:bar',
                component: Sub,
                onEnter: function(){
                    // *****************************    
                   // grab the value 'bar' from param 
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onEnter` function takes two arguments. nextState and transition. The value you're looking for is inside of `nextState.params`:

```
onEnter: function(nextState, transition) {
    let bar = nextState.params.bar;
}
```